# Return comments_link() instead of echoing it

Tags: comments

Is there a way to return the comments link instead of echoing it? I've been searching the Codex for a little while now, without being able to find a function that just returns the link and doesn't echo it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [get_comments_link()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L518), it retrieve the link without echoing it.
This is the function that is used by `comments_link()`.

See also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_link

Comment: Thanks, I looked on the Codex and it said it was deprecated so I wasn't sure.